# Persistent profile data on refresh using angularFireAuth

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Currently I am using the `$on('angularFireAuth:login', function(evt,auth){...get other profile info...})` to populate the user's profile and authorization details after they login. That stuff is added to an authService to be easily accessed throughout the app later, without putting it in the `$rootscope`.
The problem is this doesn't trigger on a refresh, or reopen. The user is still authenticated due to the session token or whatnot but, they need to relogin to load the other profile stuff.

What is the proper solution for this?
Is there an undocumented event I should use instead of login?

Here's the app.js I'm working with:

```
angular.module('myApp',['firebase']).
    constant({FirebaseUrl:"https://<foo>.firebaseio.com/"}).
    service('authService', function authService(){
        return {
            isLogged:false,
            name:null,
            email:null,
            id:null,
            group:null,
            err:null
        }
    }).
    controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope, authService, angularFireAuth, angularFireCollection, FirebaseUrl){
        angularFireAuth.initialize(FirebaseUrl, {scope:$scope, name:"auth"});
        $scope.login = function(){
            angularFireAuth.login('password', {
                email: 'test@test.foo',
                password: 'test'
                });
        }
        $scope.$on("angularFireAuth:login",function(evt,auth){
            url = FirebaseUrl + 'profiles/user-' + $scope.auth.id;
            $scope.url = url;
            var fbref = new Firebase(url);
            fbref.once('value',function(profileSnapshot){
                $scope.name = profileSnapshot.child('name').val();
                $scope.group = profileSnapshot.child('group').val();
            });
            //set authService stuff
            authService.name = $scope.name;
            authService.group = $scope.group;
            authService.email = $scope.auth.email;
            authService.id = $scope.auth.id;
            authService.isLogged = true;
        });

        $scope.logout = function(){
            angularFireAuth.logout();
            authService.email = null;
            authService.id = null;
            authService.isLogged = false;
            authService.name = null;
            authService.group = null;
        }
    }).
    controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, authService){

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should decouple the profile information from the authentication events, since as you have noticed, those events are only triggered when the authentication state changes. You should have a separate service or factory that handles profile info, which is called upon page load (if the user is logged in) and upon an authentication event.

Comment: Ahh, that would be a sensible approach. Do you know of any examples I could use as a guide. I'm still pretty noob.

Comment: I would dig around in the AngularFire [showcase](http://angularfire.com/showcase.html). You'll learn a lot by reading through the source code in those projects.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firereader/ it is. It would be nice if one of them addressed authorization in addition to authentication.